# sending zlib compress data to server using POST

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

I want to send zlib compressed data of file to server using POST request. Following is the code I am trying to use

```
orig = open('fileName', 'r').read()
comp = zlib.compress(orig, 9)

req = Request(url, comp)
urlopen(req)
```

But I get the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 2: invalid start byte`

I tried following `comp.encode('utf-8')` but this also doesn't work. I get the same `UnicodeDecodeError` at some position. How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [urllib2.Request](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request)'s `data` parameter state:

> data should be a buffer in the standard application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

You can encode your buffer using [urllib.quote](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote):

```
>>> orig = 'aaaaabbbccddxddaaabb'
>>> comp = zlib.compress(orig, 9)
>>> comp
'x\xdaKL\x04\x82\xa4\xa4\xa4\xe4\xe4\x94\x94\x8a\x94\x140\x07\x00Q\x19\x07\xc1'
>>> quoted = quote(comp)
>>> quoted
'x%DAKL%04%82%A4%A4%A4%E4%E4%94%94%8A%94%140%07%00Q%19%07%C1'
>>> req = Request('http://example.com', quoted)
```